# Generate SQL Statements from CSV in Python (Dictionaries, JSON, List)

Tags: python, json, pandas, list, dictionary

The idea is to read in a CSV File a table like the following:

[image]

```
DATABASE,SCHEMA,TABLE,COLUMN,TYPE,LENGTH
D1,S1,T1,C1,NUMBER,5
D1,S1,T1,C2,VARCHAR,25
D1,S1,T2,C1,NUMBER,5
D1,S1,T2,C2,VARCHAR,25
D1,S2,T1,C1,NUMBER,5
D1,S2,T1,C2,VARCHAR,25
D1,S2,T2,C1,NUMBER,5
D1,S2,T2,C2,VARCHAR,25
```

And in python create the corresponding query in a string variable, for example:

```
create table <s1>.<t1> (c1 number(5), c2 varchar(25));
create table <s1>.<t2> (c1 number(5), c2 varchar(25));
create table <s2>.<t1> (c1 number(5), c2 varchar(25));
create table <s2>.<t2> (c1 number(5), c2 varchar(25));
```

My idea is to store the table in a json array or I can use pandas, but I don't know what would be the simplest way to carry it out according to the iterations to be used

Comment: Do you mind putting a csv version that can be copied into a text editor?

Comment: I added the table so you can copy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your DataFrame is `df`, use:

```
groups = df.groupby(["SCHEMA", "TABLE"]).agg({"COLUMN": list, "TYPE": list, "LENGTH": list})
for (schema, table), row in groups.iterrows():
    record = zip(row["COLUMN"], row["TYPE"], row["LENGTH"])
    columns = ", ".join(f"{column} {type_}({length})" for column, type_, length in record)
    sentence = f"create table <{schema}>.<{table}> {columns};"
    print(sentence)
```

**Output**

```
create table <S1>.<T1> C1 NUMBER(5), C2 VARCHAR(25);
create table <S1>.<T2> C1 NUMBER(5), C2 VARCHAR(25);
create table <S2>.<T1> C1 NUMBER(5), C2 VARCHAR(25);
create table <S2>.<T2> C1 NUMBER(5), C2 VARCHAR(25);
```